# What's the difference between exposing environment variables in nextjs through the next.config.js vs with the NEXT_PUBLIC prefix?

Tags: javascript, next.js, environment-variables, server-side-rendering

According to the `nextjs` documentation, if I want to [expose my environment variables to the browser](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser) I can just prefix them with `NEXT_PUBLIC` in my `.env.local` file, like so:

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_VAR=7
```

However, it looks like I can *also* expose my environment variables to the browser by using `next.config.js`, like so:

```js
module.exports = {
  env: {
    PUBLIC_VAR: process.env.PUBLIC_VAR,
  },
}
```

And this will [add to the javascript bundle](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/environment-variables)

What is the difference between these two strategies?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`NEXT_PUBLIC` is a new feature added. Before, in order to set up environment variables, we had to set up both server and client, separately.

Environment variables that are placed in the .env file would be available only on the server-side, if you want to make your env variables available on the client-side you had to use `next.config.js`. We follow the separation of concerns principle here.

But setting env variables for the browser in the `next.config` was too much unnecessary typing. This was an example in `next.config.js` for the client side env:

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    AUTH0_NAMESPACE: process.env.AUTH0_NAMESPACE,
    BASE_URL: process.env.BASE_URL
  }
}
```

With `NEXT_PUBLIC`, env variables will be available both client-side and server-side. env variables that are set with `NEXT_PUBLIC` will be exposed to the browser. So make sure that you do not expose sensitive data to the browser.

So in summary, adding the prefix `NEXT_PUBLIC` to your environment variables will have the same effect of exposing to the browser your environment variables as exposing them through `next.config.js`.

try this:

place this to .env or env.development file. NOT to `next.config.js`

```
 MY_VAR=10
```

then run this:

```
    console.log("MY var",process.env.MY_VAR);
```

both inside client component and `getServerSideProps` function.
if you check the browser console, you will get `undefined`, but on terminal, you will see

```
MY var 10
```

Comment: But it sounds like now it doesn't matter which one you use?

Comment: @PatrickCollins env variables that set with NEXT_PUBLIC will be exposed to the browser. with using .env and next.config.js, we follow separation of concerns principle

Comment: So using both `NEXT_PUBLIC` and setting them up in the `next.config.js` exposes them. You're saying setting them up in the config is better because it follows separation of concerns?

Comment: yes. correct. And Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

The difference between to the two is the one of them uses a .env file whereas the other uses the next.config file. Since Next.js 9.4, loading environment variables with .env files are now supported.

However, to clarify one thing in your question, all environment variables within the .env file don't have to be prefixed with `NEXT_PUBLIC`, only the ones you want exposed to the browser, any without that prefix will only be accessible on the server.

Comment: But if I put them in the `next.config.js` they will still also be exposed to the browser?

Comment: Yes, they will.

Comment: @juliomalves won't that defeat the purpose of envs? Aren't they designed to stop important keys being leaked to end users? so whats the point to expose them to the browser in the first place?

Comment: @28364jgasd63 It depends what you use them for. If you don't want them exposed to the browser then don't use them in client-side code - keep them on the server.

Comment: @juliomalves I saw somewhere that its ideal for environment, for example setting a public env for base url and changed that based on environment. Is there any use for a public env?