# How to use ethers.js-JsonRpcProvider with Next.js to retrieve onchain data?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, ethereum, smartcontracts, ethers.js

I'm trying to read some on-chain data with ethers.js JsonRpcProvider. I'm calling it with an Alchemy key, stored in a .env file.

edit : Making this variable only visible to server side is intentionnal, because I do not want to share this "sensible" information. Maybe it's not the right way to  do this,  I don't know...

I can't load my data on the client side, but on the server side, everything seems fine :/

What I'm doing wrong?

```js
// ALCHEMY_API_KEY_URL is in .env file
const passiveProvider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(process.env.ALCHEMY_API_KEY_URL)

// everything's fine on server side
console.log(passiveProvider)

const whiteListContract = new ethers.Contract(WHITELIST_CONTRACT_ADDRESS, abi, passiveProvider)

export default function Home() {
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState("")

    React.useEffect(() => {
        async function getNumAddressesWhitelisted(contract) {
            try {
                // we're in useEffect, client-side, nothing works here :/
                
                // dunno if this executes
                const clientTx = await contract.numAddressesWhitelisted()

                console.log("numAddressesWhitelisted : ", clientTx)
                setValue(clientTx)
            } catch (err) {
                // we drop here each time
                console.log("there is an error ! ",err)
                // error message dropped :
                // there is an error !  Error: could not detect network (event="noNetwork", code=NETWORK_ERROR, version=providers/5.7.0)
                //    at Logger.makeError (index.js?dd68:224:1)
                //    at Logger.throwError (index.js?dd68:233:1)
                //    at JsonRpcProvider.eval (json-rpc-provider.js?8679:442:1)
                //    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
                //    at rejected (json-rpc-provider.js?8679:6:42)
            }

        }
        getNumAddressesWhitelisted(whiteListContract)
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            {value}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I've figured out a righter/cleaner way to do this by far :

I needed [getServerSideProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props). getServerSideProps can only exist in a next.js page, executes code on server side only, and returns props passed to the page.

The logs appears only on server side too, as expected :

```js
export async function getServerSideProps() {
    // ALCHEMY_API_KEY_URL is defined in .env file, it's visible only from server side
    const passiveProvider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(process.env.ALCHEMY_API_KEY_URL)
    console.log("passive provider : ", passiveProvider)
    const whiteListContract = new ethers.Contract(WHITELIST_CONTRACT_ADDRESS, abi, passiveProvider)
    const clientTx = await whiteListContract.numAddressesWhitelisted()
    console.log("numAddressesWhitelisted : ", clientTx)

    return { props: { clientTx } }
}

export default function Home({ clientTx }) {

    return (
        <div>
            {clientTx}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this line with the env variable is the issue:

```
const passiveProvider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(process.env.ALCHEMY_API_KEY_URL)
```

Because environment variables that are inside `.env` file loaded on the server but not on the client. so `passiveProvider` is successfully defined on server side but client-side. In order to that env variable work on the client side, you have to add `NEXT_PUBLIC_` prefix to the naming

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_ALCHEMY_API_KEY_URL=...........
```

now this env variable will be defined on the client side

```
const passiveProvider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ALCHEMY_API_KEY_URL)
```

[What's the difference between exposing environment variables in nextjs through the next.config.js vs with the NEXT_PUBLIC prefix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70764556/whats-the-difference-between-exposing-environment-variables-in-nextjs-through-t/70766460#70766460)