# Firestore not receiving data when using setDoc

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I have a problem with my app connecting to my Firestore database when trying to use setDoc.

I have the database up and running for next-auth which is functioning as intended and creating records in the database. However, when I try and allow the rest of my app to use the database I cannot get the data to update.

I believe the problem could be to do with my config file not firing correctly but its hard to know for sure as I am not getting any errors. The onClick fires (tested) and the update does not occur.

I will provide some console screenshots and code to try and make clear the problem.

/firebase/config.js

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  appId: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
  projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const storage = getStorage(app);
const db = getFirestore(app);

export { storage, db };
```

Then here is my form submit to add the form field values to an existing document.

/components/signup/SignupSubmit.js

```
import { getSession } from "next-auth/react";
import { setDoc, doc } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "../../firebase/config";

export default async function SignupSubmit(value) {
  const session = await getSession();
  const userId = session.user.id;

  const values = {
    profile: value.profile,
    screenName: value.screenName,
  };

  const docRef = doc(db, "users", `${userId}`);
  console.log(docRef);

  setDoc(docRef, { values }, { merge: true })
    .then(() => {
      console.log("Document has been updated successfully");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

I have screenshot the output of console.log(docRef).
[image: docRef output]

Let me know if I can provide any further information as I am keen to put this issue to bed.

Thanks in advance for any and all help.

UPDATE: Here is my _app code

/pages/_app.js

```
import React from "react";
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";
import { SWRConfig } from "swr";

import Layout from "../components/Layout.js";
import AccountSettingsLayout from "../components/AccountSettingsLayout";

import "../styles/globals.css";

export default function App({ Component, router, pageProps }) {
  if (router.pathname.startsWith("/auth/")) {
    return (
      <React.StrictMode>
        <SessionProvider session={pageProps.session}>
          <SWRConfig>
            <AccountSettingsLayout>
              <Component {...pageProps} />
            </AccountSettingsLayout>
          </SWRConfig>
        </SessionProvider>
      </React.StrictMode>
    );
  }

  return (
    <React.StrictMode>
      <SessionProvider session={pageProps.session}>
        <SWRConfig>
          <Layout>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
          </Layout>
        </SWRConfig>
      </SessionProvider>
    </React.StrictMode>
  );
}
```

**UPDATE - 01/10/22**

I am using Next-auth in this project which is creating users and data in firebase without issue. Could this be preventing the rest of my app from using the firestore to add data?

Here is my next-auth code..

/pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].js

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import EmailProvider from "next-auth/providers/email";
import { FirestoreAdapter } from "@next-auth/firebase-adapter";

const authOptions = {
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
    }),
    EmailProvider({
      server: {
        host: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_HOST,
        port: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_PORT,
        auth: {
          user: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_USER,
          pass: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_PASSWORD,
        },
      },
      from: process.env.EMAIL_FROM,
    }),
  ],
  session: {
    jwt: false,
  },
  adapter: FirestoreAdapter({
    apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    appId: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_ID,
    authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    databaseURL: process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
    projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  }),
  theme: {
    colorScheme: "dark",
  },
  pages: {
    signIn: "/auth/signin",
    newUser: "/auth/signup",
  },
  debug: false,
  callbacks: {
    async signIn({ user, account, profile }) {
      if (account.provider === "google") {
        return profile.email_verified;
      }
      return true;
    },
    async redirect({ url, baseUrl }) {
      return baseUrl;
    },
    async session({ session, user }) {
      session.user.id = user.id;
      return Promise.resolve(session);
    },
    async jwt({ token, user, account, profile, isNewUser }) {
      return token;
    },
  },
};
export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you received any errors while executing the function? Does your `.then()` and `.catch()` logs any info?

Comment: The .then and .catch logs dont get activated and i have no idea why. No errors are returned with the code as is. I can log the value and it returns my form values from inside this function. I have shared the log i get for docRef to show it returns the path as per my database structure. But zero errors and so i am in the dark about why. Thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is with your env variables. In the first screenshot you get this options

```
_options : ( apiKey : undefined , appId : undefined , authDomain : undefined , databaseURL : undefined
```

Your env variables defined correctly in `next-auth` config, because `next-auth` page is `pages/apis/auth/[...nextauth].js` file. `apis` directory is executed on the server and since env variables that you set in `env` are by default available on the server, your configuration worked here.

since, in the beginning yourfirestore config run on the client side, `process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY` env variables were `undefined`. To make the env variables both available on client and server, use `NEXT_PUBLIC` prefix in env file.

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY=#####################
```

then use it as `process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY`.

[What's the difference between exposing environment variables in nextjs through the next.config.js vs with the NEXT_PUBLIC prefix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70764556/whats-the-difference-between-exposing-environment-variables-in-nextjs-through-t/70766460#70766460)

Comment: Yilmaz, Thank you so much! I had a feeling that the issue was being caused by this which is why i screenshot and highlighted in yellow but i had no idea how to fix the problem. I wasn't sure if the log was showing undefined so as the mask the values or not as a security measure. It didn't help that firebase gave me no errors! I really appreciate you taking the time and only hope that anyone else having this problem in the future can use this solution to save them days of hardship! Firebase really should have something on their site to explain this implementation to people. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the firebase-admin package to initialize the app, but you are using the firebase package to update the document, so you can try to use the firebase-admin package to update the document. Example:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";
import { setDoc, doc } from "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  appId: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
  projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const storage = getStorage(app);
const db = getFirestore(app);

export { storage, db };

import { db } from "../../firebase/config";

export default async function SignupSubmit(value) {

  const values = {
    profile: value.profile,
    screenName: value.screenName,
  };

  const docRef = doc(db, "users", `${userId}`);
  console.log(docRef);

  setDoc(docRef, { values }, { merge: true })
    .then(() => {
      console.log("Document has been updated successfully");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Tibic4. The result is the same. I actually had it set this way for a while before trying curly braces. This results in the same output. Nothing gets logged from the then/catch, the db receives no new data and there are no errors. Any other ideas?

Comment: I will edit the answer see if it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried your suggestion and the outcome is the same. I am not sure why you think i am using firebase-admin though as the setup in my config file is standard firestore. Would love to know more about what is pointing to firebase-admin. I dont even have the firebase-admin package installed.