# Why can I not access my env variables in NextJs?

Tags: next.js, environment-variables

I am creating a next js project. I am using this template: **https://github.com/theodorusclarence/ts-nextjs-tailwind-starter**

I am trying to create a supabase client. I put the `SUPABASE_URL` and `SUPABASE_ANON_KEY` in my `.env` file.

```
    import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js';
            
    import { Database } from '@/types/database';
    
    export const supabaseClient = createClient<Database>(
      process.env.SUPABASE_URL as string,
      process.env.SUPABASE_ANON_KEY as string
    );

console.log('url', process.env.SUPABASE_URL)
console.log('keyss', process.env.SUPABASE_ANON_KEY)
```

When I try to access the variables via `process.env.SUPABASE_ANON_KEY` and `process.env.SUPABASE_URL`, I get the error that "`Supabase url and key is requried`".

When I console.log the values of the variables, I get the log statements in my vs code terminal but not in my browser.

When I put the strings as it is in the code, instead of accessing them via process.env. I get no errors and everything works fine.

Is there some issue with the browser not being able to access the env variables?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70764556/whats-the-difference-between-exposing-environment-variables-in-nextjs-through-t/70766460#70766460

Comment: r u trying to reach in client component?

Comment: okk, I added NEXT_PUBLIC to the names of the variables and it worked. Yes, I am actually trying to use the supabase client in a client component. 
Thanks!

Comment: be careful when using `NEXT_PUBLIC` prefix. those variables will be exposed to client bundle.